# Does the @JavascriptInterface is usable in a webView enviroment

Tags: android

Does the `@JavascriptInterface` attribute is usable only in a `webView` environment?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking about. Please add more detail to your question.

Comment: Where else would you use it?

Comment: I want use the `@JavascriptInterface` when I request from an activity that it has no the `WebView` widget, as the result I should can get the data from server using the `@JavascriptInterface` attribute. The `WebView` class has methods like the `webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");` but I do not know this for when I do not want use the `WebView` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To communicate with a server without displaying something in a webview, use a `URLConnection`. JavascriptInterface has nothing (*absolutely nothing*) to do with this.